# Is there a way to create a URL that will be opened in mobile browser and not in facebook native uiwebview

Tags: javascript, facebook, uiwebview

I'm trying to develop a web site (outside of Facebook) that all users will reach from within Facebook native apps.
currently when I publish a URL: http://mysite.com and a user clicks on it from within Facebook native app (galaxy 3+ and iphone 4+), the site is opened in the uiwebview of the application. I want it to be opened always in the default browser of the device.
is this possible? Thanks